# NullPointerException uising PageFactory

Tags: java, selenium, page-factory

I just started using page factory but I can seem to figure out what is causing the null point exception in my code. Its most likely an issue with how I'm calling the driver but don't know how to resolve it

Managing my webdriver here

```
    public class Browser {

    public static WebDriver driver;


    public static void setup() {
        ChromeOptions handlingSSL = new ChromeOptions();
        handlingSSL.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(handlingSSL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void quit() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The prep for my TC

```
    public class Base {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        Browser.setup();
        Browser.driver.get("https://example.com");
    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void quit() {
        Browser.quit();
    }
}
```

The page class with all the elements

```
    public  class LoginPage {

    @FindBy (id = "username")
    WebElement username;
    @FindBy (id = "password")
    WebElement password;
    @FindBy (xpath = "//button[contains(text(), 'Sign')]")
    WebElement sign;


        public void logIn(String userName, String passWord) {
            username.sendKeys(userName);
            password.sendKeys(passWord);
            sign.click();
        }
    }
```

I've tried adding the constructor method in the page call as well but it was a no go as well

```
public class LoginPageTest extends Base {

    LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(Browser.driver, LoginPage.class);

    @Test
    public void verifyLoginTest(){
        loginPage.logIn("user","pass");
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at pages.LoginPage.logIn(LoginPage.java:18)
    at login.LoginPageTest.verifyLoginTest(LoginPageTest.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Comment: on which line is the exception thrown? you'll have to provide the stack trace in order to help us understand your problem...my only guess so far is that one (or all) of your WebElements couldn't be located

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NullPointerException at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849531/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-openqa-selenium-support-pagefactory-defaul)

Comment: ```LoginPage loginPage @BeforeMethod
public void createDriver() {
loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(Browser.driver, LoginPage.class);
}```Can you try to initialise it in the before method and use it ?

Comment: The reason you are getting null pointer is, loginpage is not been initialized and you are trying to access the method on the null.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to have a constructor in your LoginPage.java and define a private object for driver in that class something like this :

```
private WebDriver driver;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
     this.driver = driver;
}
```

Comment: Still getting the NullPointerException :(

Comment: I hope you have placed this line inside the test as others have mentioned... `LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(Browser.driver, LoginPage.class);`